# Correct Django Foreignkey setup with legacy database

Tags: django

I used `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py` to create models from my old SQL database. `Workout.user_id` is a foreign key to `users` table, but `inspectdb` lost this linking by making it just `models.IntegerField()`.

Database looks like this:

```
Users
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Bob        |
|  2 | Alice      |
|  3 | Tom        |
+----+------------+

Workout
+---------+------------+------------+
| user_id | workout_id | date       |
+---------+------------+------------+
|       2 |          1 | 2021-02-18 |
|       2 |          2 | 2021-02-20 |
|       3 |          3 | 2021-02-21 |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

And models.py comes out like this:

```
# This is an auto-generated Django model module.
# You'll have to do the following manually to clean this up:
#   * Rearrange models' order
#   * Make sure each model has one field with primary_key=True
#   * Make sure each ForeignKey and OneToOneField has `on_delete` set to the desired behavior
#   * Remove `managed = False` lines if you wish to allow Django to create, modify, and delete the table
# Feel free to rename the models, but don't rename db_table values or field names.
from django.db import models


class Users(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'users'


class Workout(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    workout_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'workout'
```

`Workout.user_id` is a foreign key to `users` table, but `inspectdb` lost this linking by making it just `models.IntegerField()`.

I tried setting ForeignKey like this:

```
user_id = models.ForeignKey('Users', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but it gives an error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'workout.user_id_id' in 'field list'")
```

Can this kind of ForeignKey linking be achieved or how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django automatically adds `_id` to the `ForeignKey` for the name of the table column, you thus name it `user`. You can also specify with the [**`db_column=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-column) the name of the database column, although that is not necessary here:

```
class Workout(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'Users',
        db_column='user_id'
    )
    workout_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'workout'
```